# Is there an iPad whiteboard that can also be used on desktop machines?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, desktop

I've seen many iPad whiteboard apps but all seem to be either iPad only (eg Whiteboard Mojo) or are read-only from the web (Jot) or require local connection via wifi (splashtop) or make you pay for every Internet session (whiteboard HD). I don't mind paying for the app, but I want to use this for business, and nickel and diming per session isn't going to work. (How would people get reimbursed?)

So I want an app I can buy once and use for as many Internet whiteboard sessions with other iPads and desktop machines as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it would be a good solution for you. No installation required, it should run on almost any desktop.

### [A Web Whiteboard](http://awwapp.com/)

---

This product also may meet your needs.

### [NotateIt](http://www.notateit.com/default.aspx?m=1)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried WizIQ’s education apps for mobile learning on your iPad or Android tablet [(http://www.wiziq.com/mobile/](http://www.wiziq.com/mobile/) ? 
I suggest you have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at it. Sorry I can't +1 you, not enough reputation. (I would think StackOverflow reputation would apply here, but apparently not.)

Answer (score 0):

Try Jot!. It's a whiteboard app that you can also use in desktop pc's through it's Live Sharing feature.

visit https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jot!-whiteboard-free/id371937922?mt=8 for more info.

Disclosure: I am affiliated with the makers of this app.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please read the FAQ, specifically [this paragraph](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) about self promoting! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these 3 
http://idienstler.de/759/3-kostenlose-online-whiteboards/
the first is my personal favourite.

Comment: Can you please summarize the content of the linked page? Links may break rendering your answer useless, the goal is to have answers standing on their own. In addition it would be interesting to learn more about the usability of these services on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I am strongly interested in the product I suggest below, so maybe I am biased unintentionally, but I try to be as object and factual as possible.

[Ziteboard is a virtual whiteboard](https://ziteboard.com) web app running on any device with any operating systems with all major web browsers. The service is optimized for Ipad with Safari as it stated in the [FAQ page](https://ziteboard.com/faq/). It's clutter free UI design ensures that the service run even on smart phone. Cross-platform is important when you don't know (in advance) that your collaborators what device use.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you please disclose your affiliation with the product in your profile *and in the answer* The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

Comment: @nohillside - I flagged as SPAM because the author's profile page is all about Ziteboard.  This should be closed/deleted as appropriate.

Comment: Post edited, thanks. Can you please explain why my post is not 100% relevant and good?